# Why can my command line not recognize Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, command-line-interface, r-markdown

I am brand new to R and RMarkdown. I don't have any interest in actually using RStudio, I just want to run my RMarkdown commands on command line to generate PDF's. I have R, RStudio, and Mactex downloaded.I have the following file in my home directory:

`DataAnalytics.Rmd`

```
---
 title: "Data Analytics in RMarkdown"
 author: "Jennetta George"
 output:
   pdf_document: default
---
```

On the command line, I try running in my home directory

```
Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('DataAnalytics.Rmd')"
```

which gives the error

```
zsh: no matches found: "rmarkdown::render('DataAnalytics.Rmd')"
```

or I try running

```
echo "rmarkdown::render('DataAnalytics.Rmd', clean=TRUE)" | R --slave
```

and get the error

```
 Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘rmarkdown’
 Calls: :: ... loadNamespace -> withRestarts -> withOneRestart -> doWithOneRestart
 Execution halted
```

I have googled endlessly for a solution but there is not a lot out there on RMarkdown CLI. Would really appreciate some help troubleshooting this.

Comment: Have you installed `rmarkdown`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed! In RStudio, I ran:

`install.packages('knitr', dependencies = TRUE)`

and

`install.packages('markdown', dependencies = TRUE)`

and now it works.